# Java selenium - Selecting elements in dropDown

Tags: java, selenium, dropdown

I am trying to select an element in a dropDown.
my problem is that i can't open the dropDown. What ever i try it doesn't work.

I have located the dropDown :

```
WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='chosen-single']"));
```

But when i perform a click - Nothing happens.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please share HTML in text format and if you get - error

Comment: need more info atleast the error message

Answer (score 1):

In case your dropdown list corresponds to an HTML `<select>` tag, you could uniquely locate the element (using id, class, XPath etc) and then create a Selenium Select instance:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("myDropdownElementId"));
Select dropDownSelect = new Select(element);
```

After creating the Selenium Select instance, you can use any of the following ways to pick an option from the dropdown list:

```
// select by index
dropDownSelect.selectByIndex(2);
// select by value
dropDownSelect.selectByValue("Car");
// select by visible text  
dropDownSelect.selectByVisibleText("CarText");
```